# Pass gradle argument with space

Tags: java, gradle, cmd, space

I am trying to run my java main class from gradle.

`run -Pargs="argument key=value"`

eg:  `run -Pargs="argument folder="C:/Temp" "` this works

But when i try to provide a folder with spaces, it does not work:

`run -Pargs="argument folder="C:/Temp/sample folder" "` does not work

`run -Pargs="argument folder="C:/Temp/sample\\ folder" "` does not work

The error says
Task 'folder' not found in project

Any thoughts ?

Comment: Basically, if there is a space in FILE_PATH, then you need to enclose the whole path in quotes "C:/Temp/sample folder".

Comment: tried that too, if you see my first  example run -Pargs="argument folder="C:/Temp/sample folder" "

Comment: You'll need to escape the nested quotes, or try a mix of matching single and double quotes.